# Xamarin aar binding. Many class declaration missed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, aar

I'm trying to accomplish the .aar file binding to the Xamarin Android project.
I used Bindings Library (Android) project, include my aar to there and build. Everything went Ok.

In Xamarin Android project I added a reference to the generated .dll

It appeared to have only a couple of interfaces exposed but the aar has tons of classes surfaced for sure (I can see them in Android Studio).
Where are the other classes and members?

What I did:
I modified my Metada.xml as following (to expose private declarations and suppress obfuscation). Please ignore its "(" brackets, it is for correct display.

```
  <metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.biomini']/class[@name='BioMiniAndroid']"
        name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.android.biomini']/class[@name='BioMiniAndroid']"
        name="obfuscated">false</attr>
</metadata>
```

It did not help. How to make it show me all classes and interfaces the .aar has?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a correct path to fix these issue by making the types `public`.

There are bunch of reasons why JAR file classes/member are not accessible in the Xamarin.Android project, you can read about there reasons and possible solutions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/#Problem_Missing_C_types_in_generated_output.)

I recommend reading JAR binding [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

All that had been read inside out. No solution found.
The problem appeared to be a Xamarin bug. Xamarin recommendation is not to reference it to a binding project but copy .dll to somewhere aside and reference to there (via "Browse" referencing, not "Solution" one). Even though it is awkward it works. It is a viable solution for now.

Thanks.